# Dygraph's %>% replacing Dplyr's

Tags: r, dplyr, dygraphs

I'm writing a package that imports shiny, dygraphs and shiny. However, whenever I'm Build & Load the package, there's always a warning, `replacing previous imports by 'dygraphs::%>%' when loading mypkg`.

I've tried change the order in `DESCRIPTION`, but it doesn't work. Also, the package uses a lot of dplyr functions as well as dygraphs', so I can't just say `importFrom`, otherwise it will be a long list. Therefore, is there any way to *not* import `dygraphs::%>%` or `dplyr::%>%` into my package? Or is there any other way to solve this warning? Thanks!

Comment: pick one of the two and enumerate the imports you need with `importFrom`. as a pkg creator, you will have to compensate for no `importAllExceptFor` ability and list'em all out. it's rly not that bad. Dygraph's [NAMESPACE](https://github.com/rstudio/dygraphs/blob/master/NAMESPACE) is teensy. Just import all of what you need from there but the it's re-exported magrittr pipe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to "not import" something from a package. You can check the user manual for Roxygen2, and in the "import" section there is no such command. You might still want to use importFrom for dplyr. You just need to import the following functions:

select filter mutate arrange group_by ungroup summarise left_join tbl_df

I think these are all the functions you need to import, but you can add more when you see errors. It should not take more than 10 minutes to find out every function you used in the dplyr package.